# how to check laravel policy authorization in laravel request class?

Tags: laravel, sentinel, policies

I am using policies in my application. And for example, one user has a role customer-role. This customer-role has the customer.view permission. and in my customer policy I am checking like this.

```
public function view(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasAccess('customer.view');
    }
```

And from getcustomer request class:

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return Gate::allows('view', 'App\Models\Customer') ? true : false;
    }
```

But this always returns false. Please someone help me here as am new to Laravel.

Comment: are you currently authenticated? is the policy registered correctly?  and `Gate::allows` returns a `boolean`

Comment: yes am currently authenticated and policy registered correctly in AuthServiceProvider: 'App\Models\Customer' => 'App\Policies\CustomerPolicy'

Comment: Gate::allows return false always even if the authenticated user has the permission

Comment: are you sure `$user->hasAccess(...)` is returning what you expect?

Comment: no, at least it's not checking the view method in policy, from the request class itself returning false

Comment: you will need to find out why `$user->hasAccess(...)` doesn't return what you expect since that is what your authorization is based on

Comment: can I know why the policy method is not hitting by my request class authorize method please?

Comment: does `$user->hasAccess(...)` return what you expect ... because that is the thing that is what your authorization is based upon so you have to figure out if that is working correctly before the policy/authorization even comes into play

Comment: yes it returns true for this

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue. The problem was I've written a before() method in AuthServiceProvider as below:

```
Gate::before(function ($user) {
            if ($user->inRole('admin')) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
           }
        });
```

As this is returning false for non-admin users, it is not checking any other methods. So I had to remove the else condition from this before() method and now it is working.

This article was helpful for me.
https://blog.karmacomputing.co.uk/debugging-laravel-policies/

Comment: yea you have to be aware of the code you are actually adding to your application ...